# facebook fan page user data extraction php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-page

To extract list of users of a particular facebook fan page am using the below code

```
$text = file_get_contents('rawnike.php');
 //  $text = file_get_contents('http://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=10000&id=15087023444');

   $text = preg_replace("/<script[^>]+\>/i", "", $text);
   $text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $text);


$pattern = '!(https?://[^\s]+)!'; // refine this for better/more specific results

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches)) {
    list(, $links) = ($matches);
    //print_r($links); 
    //var_dump($links);
}

unset($links[0]);unset($links[1]);unset($links[2]);unset($links[3]);unset($links[4]);unset($links[5]);unset($links[6]);unset($links[7]);
 //var_dump($links);
 $links=str_replace('https','http',$links); $links=str_replace('\"','',$links);
foreach ($links as $value) {
    echo "fb user ID: $value<br />\n";
}
```

And by this am successfully retrieving users' profile links using `file_get_contents('rawnike.php')` (rawnike.php locally saved)

but if I try to pull the same from url `file_get_contents("http://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=10000&id=15087023444")` 
 am not able to retrieve, which means I cannot extract facebook page's source directly! I should save the page's source manually!

The same I observed when parsing a user's page if I manually stores page's source code locally and parse it, am able to extract user's interest. On the other hand if I directly try to extract source code with URL, its not getting the same source.

Which means `$source=file_get_contents($url); $source="content which displays ur browser doesnt supported or some crap"`  on other hand `$source=file_get_contents($string_to_extract_content_of_local_saved_sourceFile); $source="content which i excatly needed to parse"`

On doing little research I understood that `FQL` is right approach for doing things like this. But pls help me understand why there is difference in sources code extracted and is `FQL` is the only way or in some other way I can proceed ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But pls help me understand why there is difference in sources code extracted

Because Facebook realizes by looking at the details of your HTTP request, stuff like the `User Agent` header etc., that it’s not a *real* browser used by an actual person making the request – and so they try to block you from accessing the data.

One *can* try to work around this, by providing request details that make it look more like a “real” browser – but scraping HTML pages to get the desired info is generally not the way to go, because –

> and is FQL is the only way or in some other way I can proceed ahead.

– that’s what APIs are for. FQL/the Graph API are the means that Facebook provides for you to access their data.

If there is data you are interested in, that is not provided by those – then Facebook does not really want to give you that data. The data about persons who like a page is such kind of data.

Comment: @CBore can you provide me any example `that make it look more like a “real” browser`

Comment: Use Firebug or some similar tool, to see what kind of HTTP request headers your browser sends when requesting a web page. And then try to “mimic” those values while making your HTTP request from your script. You can try setting some of those using the `context` parameter for file_get_contents; if you need more flexibility, then using cURL instead might be a good idea. (Apart from the _whole idea_ not being a good one to begin with, but I mentioned that already.)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init("https://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=10000&id=15087023444");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $data = preg_replace("%(.*?)(<div id.*?>)%is","",$data); //to strip <scripts>,<links>,<meta>,etc tags.
```

But the max connections are 100. :S

Answer (score 0):

The number of connection params cannot exceed 100, you are trying with 1000.